# Is posting puzzles from a book/magazine/newspaper a violation of PSE policy if attribution is given?

Tags: discussion

I ask because I don’t want to post puzzles here and have them subsequently closed or deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Proper attribution” for non-original puzzles: a guide](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide)

Comment: @bobble  No.  But @Jafe’s answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting puzzles from an external source like a book or newspaper is allowed on PSE. You do, however, need to provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) when posting content not created by you.